# open "Pick a Contact" with a name in the search

Tags: android, contactscontract

i want to open the contact intent with a name already in the search box. can id do that?
if so how? 
no i'm calling to the intent like that:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, SELECT_PERSON_REQUEST_CODE);
```

help any one? 
thank you from ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this feature doesn't exists.